# Logs get dumped to console all at once when the execution is over, instead of being printed in real time

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm working on a test automation project using Maven (with Surefire plugin) and TestNG. Since I have very long-running UI scripts (up to 20 minutes), I make intensive use of logging to the console. This is crucial to me, at least in the developing phase of each script. However, logs gets dumped all at once at the end of the execution, instead of being printed in real-time. I realize this makes perfect sense in case of parallel execution (to avoid overlapping issues), but I would like a way to disable this when executing in a serial fashion. I've searched both Surefire and TestNG documentations, but I can't seem to find a way. Any help would be appreciated. This is a very simple dummy project to reproduce the issue:

projectRoot/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

projectRoot/src/test/java/DummyTest.java

```
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class DummyTest {
    @Test
    public void ConsoleLoggingTest() {
        System.out.println("STARTING TEST...");
        try { Thread.sleep(30000); } catch (Exception ignored) { } //SIMULATE LONG-RUNNING TASK
        System.out.println("TEST IS FINISHED!");
    }
}
```

I use to execute tests with the `mvn test` command in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA). Please note that I used `System.out.println()` for the sake of simplicity, but I get the same behavior using any logging library, like log4j.

Comment: Reporter.log("some log",true); It will print on console

Comment: @RahulL Does that mean I can't use log4j along with TestNG (without coding some custom Appender)? I was really hoping for a quick way to disable that behavior...

Comment: You can create one wrapper logger method . Call this method everywhere  .Wrapper method will have  /og4j log() &  Reporter.log()

Comment: @RahulL that way I would have the same log line printed twice in the console; one in real time (reporter), and one at the end of execution (log4j). Not so elegant...

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, why don't you use IDE's own Tests Runner? It will print the output at the moment when it is available.

Comment: @Andrey running through the integrated TestNG runner seems to work just fine. So, do I have to assume that the culprit is Maven Surefire? Can you please explain this in detail?

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade the maven-surefire-plugin from M5 to M3 or M4? I have the same issue once I upgrade M3 to M5.